# mod-rewrite: Locating a file in multiple directories

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Here's an interesting problem:

I'm trying to separate a few files on a system into a number of packages, and to be able to access them without explicitly specifying which package a file is in.

Here's an example: Say, a file `/package1/one.htm` is in `/package1` and `/package2/two.htm` is in `/package2`. With the configuration below, I'll be able to access them directly, eg. `http://localhost/one.htm`

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/package1%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /package1$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/package2%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /package2$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/package3%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /package3$1 [L]
```

The problem is that I'd like to be able to add more packages, without updating this Apache configuration file (and without having to restart Apache). I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/package(.*)%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /package%1$1 [L]
```

But, unfortunately, the code above does not work, since it is not possible to take a match from the `RewriteCond` (the `(.*)`) and then apply it to the `RewriteRule`. At least that was my understanding of it.

Can you think of a creative way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a programmatic [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap):

```
RewriteMap rewriter prog:/path/to/script
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{rewriter:$1} [L]
```

And then in your script, take whatever part of the request path you want, iterate through your directories, and return the appropriate rewrite string.

Comment: Interesting. Do you believe there's a way to do this without a script?

Comment: I'm not coming up with anything.